# How to copy an XML node and paste in same level using XLS transformations

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation, xls

I wanted to copy a node of an xml and paste it in the same level.

Consider I have an xml as below.

```
<MyXml>
    <system>
        <Groups>
            <Group id="01" check="true">
            <name>Value</name>
            <age>test</age>
        </Group>
        <Group id="02" check="true">
            <name>Value</name>
            <age>test</age>
        </Group>
        <Group id="03" check="true">
            <name>Value</name>
            <age>test</age>
        </Group>
        </Groups>
  </system>
</MyXml>
```

I wanted to copy Group 03 and paste in the same level(inside groups) as "04" using XSL Transformations.

### Expected Output

```
<MyXml>
    <system>
        <Groups>
            <Group id="01" check="true">
                <name>Value</name>
                <age>test</age>
            </Group>
            <Group id="02" check="true">
                <name>Value</name>
                <age>test</age>
            </Group>
            <Group id="03" check="true">
                <name>Value</name>
                <age>test</age>
            </Group>
            <Group id="04" check="true">
                <name>Value</name>
                <age>test</age>
            </Group>
        </Groups>
  </system>
</MyXml>
```

Can somebody please help on completing the XSL stylesheet for the same. Not sure whether the below xsl in correct. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="groupId" />
<xsl:param name="newGroupId" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyXML/system/Groups/Group[@id=$groupId]" >
 <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <!--Wanted to do something for pasting the copied node and changing the id value with new Group Id.-->
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you want to do it using java or not?

Comment: I will use Java Transformer class to convert the same with xsl stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, it is actually considered an error to have a variable expression in a template match (although you may find some processors allow it).

But what you probably should do, is call the identity template in the template matching `Group`, and then have an `xsl:if` to decide whether to copy it.

Try this template instead

```
<xsl:template match="Group" >
  <xsl:call-template name="identity" />;
  <xsl:if test="@id = $groupId">
    <group id="{$newGroupId}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'id']|node()"/>
    </group>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Note you don't need the full path to `Group` in your template match, not unless there are `Group` elements in other levels which you don't want to match. (Additionally, your current match was referring to `MyXML`, when your XML has it as `MyXml`. XSLT is case-sensitive, so this wouldn't have matched).

Comment: Thankyou. This worked. But, the xml is written with an unwanted semicolon (</Group>;  <Group id="04" check="true">). And the new node seems to be in the same line as of the previous node. I am new to this, and unable to find the way to keep the same in next line.

Comment: This came since we have put semicolon after call template. Got the correct output on removing.